# Constructing and proving a bijection $f : [0, 1] \to [a, b]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb R$ with $a < b$ and $c < d$.
>   (i) Construct a bijection $f : [0, 1] \to [a, b]$.
>   (ii) Prove that your $f$ from (i) is a bijection.
>   (iii) Prove that $|[a, b]| = |[c, d]|$.

I don't know where to start. Please help.

Comment: Please learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, if you do not provide any of your own work, then expect hints instead of complete solutions or having your question placed [on-hold](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most natural thing to do is to take $f$ to be the line passing through $(0,a)$ and $(1,b)$. (iii) follows from (ii) as two sets $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection $f : A \to B$.

Comment: Can you explain your answer for (i) and (ii)?

Comment: Elaborating on the answer of Ethan Alwaise: Take the plane, draw $x$-axis and $y$-axis. In $x$-xis mark the interval $[0,1]$ in red and in the $y$-axis do the same for the *vertical* interval $[a,b]$. Now draw the graph of the $f$ ( a line  segment) given in this answer. From each point of the graph you can reach a unique point in the coloured intervals by moving parallel to the axes. This gives a bijection geometrically.

Comment: Do I draw a line segment from [0,1] to [a,b] on the graph?